Derived class member function not implicitly converted to base class member function
In the following code, there are generic classes reg and regmap and a user-defined class mymap which is derived from the regmap class.
In the mymap class, the user creates instances of reg and registers a callback function which is executed when reg.read() is called.
Here is complete code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class regmap;
class reg {
    public:

    typedef void(regmap::*funcPtr)(reg);
    std::function<void(reg)> callback_func;

    void register_callback_func(regmap* map,funcPtr func){
        callback_func = std::bind(func,map,std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    reg(string name):name(name){
        callback_func = nullptr;
    }
    void read(){
        if(callback_func){
            callback_func(*this);
        }
    }
    string name;
};

class regmap {
    public:
    regmap(){
    }
    virtual ~regmap(){
    }
};

class mymap : public regmap {
    public:
    mymap():regmap(){
        reg r1("r1");
        //r1.register_callback_func(this,static_cast<void (regmap::*)(reg)>(&mymap::user_function));
        r1.register_callback_func(this,&mymap::user_function);
        r1.read();
    }
    void user_function(reg r){
        cout<<" ....user_finction...."<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    mymap map;
    return 0;
}

The above code gives a compilation error:
test3_1.cpp: In constructor ‘mymap::mymap()’:
test3_1.cpp:41:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘reg::register_callback_func(mymap*, void (mymap::*)(reg))’
         r1.register_callback_func(this,&mymap::user_function);
                                                             ^
test3_1.cpp:13:10: note: candidate: void reg::register_callback_func(regmap*, reg::funcPtr)
     void register_callback_func(regmap* map,funcPtr func){
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test3_1.cpp:13:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘void (mymap::*)(reg)’ to ‘reg::funcPtr {aka void (regmap::*)(reg)}’

It looks like the derived class member function is not implicitly converted to a base class member function.
I have a few workaround for this:

r1.register_callback_func(this,static_cast<void (regmap::*)(reg)>(&mymap::user_function));

I use std::bind() in register_callback_func args


But I want to make the callback register from the user as simple as possible, and this is why I choose r1.register_callback_func(this,&mymap::user_function);
Any solution to this?

Neat question. Tactical note: rather than std::bind, consider using a lambda expression. Less  deep magic involved and often optimizes better.

The rule for pointer-to-member-function agrees with the rule for pointer-to-data-member, so A: Cannot cast "member pointer to derived class" to "member pointer to base class" applies. But I think you are more interested in how to work around this than why this is an issue?

Why not have directly void register_callback_func(std::function<void(reg)>)? User would just do r1.register_callback_func([this](reg r){ this->user_function(r););.

The language's rule is that it is okay to implicitly convert a base type's pointer-to-member to a derived type's pointer-to-member, but not the other way around. This is good, because if the pointed-to member is in the base class, then it is in the derived class, but not vice versa. A conversion from Derived::* to Base::* could lead to a pointer to something that does not exist. The language requires an explicit confirmation from the programmer that this is intended.
In your case, you want to shield users of your class from having to give this explicit confirmation (a.k.a. static_cast). I'd say this is good, because the conversion is semantically an implementation detail of reg. One solution is to be more liberal in what your function accepts. Instead of forcing the involvement of regmap, write a template that accepts any compatible object pointer and pointer-to-member.
    // A type alias can be a template.
    template <class T>
    using funcPtr = void(T::*)(reg);

    // A template function can accept any class.
    template <class T>
    void register_callback_func(T* map, funcPtr<T> func){
        callback_func = std::bind(func, map, std::placeholders::_1);
        // Alternatively, either of the following would also work:
        //callback_func = [=](reg param) { return (map->*func)(param); };
        //callback_func = [=](reg param) { std::invoke(func, map, param); };
    }

If for some reason you really want to restrict registration to classes derived from regmap, you could add a requires std::is_base_of_v<regmap, T> clause to the templates (you then need #include <type_traits>). However, this strikes me as unnecessarily restrictive.

If the map really has to be derived from regmap, then a more direct way to get this result is to give regmap a virtual function to be invoked as the callback, rather than delving into pointer-to-member syntax.
The drawback of this approach is that each object is restricted to a single callback. If there is a scenario where you would register different pointers-to-member-function with the same object, then this approach is inadequate. However, some people might overlook this option, so I think it's worth mentioning, at least for future visitors.
class reg;
class regmap {
  public:
    virtual ~regmap() = default;

    virtual void callback(reg) = 0;
};

With this setup, the derived class has the option to either implement the callback directly as callback() or simply call another member function from its implementation of callback(). You just need to adapt the reg class to register an object instead of an object plus a pointer-to-member-function (and being simpler is a plus).
// If the member function `read()` is defined inline, then the definition
// of `regmap` is needed. Otherwise, a forward declaration is sufficient.
class regmap;
class reg {
    regmap* callback_obj = nullptr;
  public:

    void register_callback_object(regmap* map){
        callback_obj = map;
    }

    void read(){
        if(callback_obj){
            callback_obj->callback(*this);
        }
    }
};


I changed my code as per your suggestion (using template) and I still got the error test3_1.cpp:13:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘void (mymap::*)(reg)’ to ‘reg::funcPtr {aka void (regmap::*)(reg)}’

my changes are `/*typedef void(regmap::*funcPtr)(reg);
void register_callback_func(reg r,regmap* map,funcPtr func){
    r.register_callback_func(map,func);
}*/

template <class T>
using funcPtr = void(T::*)(reg);

template <class T>
void register_callback_func(T* map, funcPtr<T> func){
    callback_func = std::bind(func, map);
}`


@KPathak Please re-check your work. The commented-out code in your comment includes a definition for register_callback_func with three parameters, but in your question it has two. This suggests you are not working from your question's code, but are instead adapting the answer (which is good) and messed up the adaptation. To be thorough, though, I copied the code from the question, replaced the definitions of funcPtr and register_callback_func with what you put in your comment, restored the missing argument to std::bind, and compiled. No errors.
